# html5 audio not playing on ios devices (ionic)

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, audio, html5-audio

I have this `html5 audio` in my `ionic app`, but when I test in in `Xcode simulator`, the `audio` is playing but when I `simulate` it in **my iPhone**, it does not work. The player only has a "`Live Broadcast`" word in it. It does not play nor have any sound.

**Here is my sample code.**

```
<audio controls>
  <source ng-src="{{track.podaudio | trustAsResourceUrl}}" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: is your url secure, I mean HTTPS.

Comment: were you able to get this working? i have similar code to you where i trust the resource in the src but still can't get anything to play.

Comment: iOS has a restriction whereby you can start playing sound only on user input, you have to remove autoplay and start the play method when there is user input.